# "_.debounce is not a function" when using lodash 4.11.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I'm completely new to lodash, but I'm trying to implement debounce as per [this article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/). I can get it using [v3.5 via this CDN](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js) but every time I try to download 4.11.1 and include it in my project I get an `Uncaught Type Error: _.debounce is not a function`.

Here's my script, pretty straightforward:

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", _.debounce(function() {
    console.log("hello world");
}, 400));
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working with the newer version of lodash? I referenced [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) and I'm not seeing anything out of place here. Very odd.

Comment: debounce doesn't execute the function, it returns the function.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh: `debounce` returns a *new* function, and that's exactly what `on` expects

Comment: How are you loading lodash? [Your example works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/u6hgmaxn/).

Comment: What's the output of `_.VERSION` in your console?

Comment: @AndréDion odd, maybe it's conflicting with something else then. I'll do more testing.

Comment: @mbaljeetsingh Why does this work in v3.5.0 then? Seems strange that it would work in one version and not another if what I'm doing is fundamentally wrong

Comment: @GG. with 3.5.0, "3.5.0". With 4.11.1, "4.11.1". Exactly what I would expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I feel dumb about this. I completely missed that there where two separate builds, "core" and "full." Apparently core doesn't come bundled with `debounce`. I've got it working now with the full script.